# vue can't use jquery 2 excel

Tags: jquery, html, vue.js

I have a html table and I am trying to download it. I am using jQuery for 
that but the framework I am using is Vue.

I tried to add the CDN to index.html in my Vue app. But when I am trying to use it functions this send me error.

I tried to include the CDN both in the component and the index.html but nothing seems to work.

CDN

```
<!--html table to excel -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
```

Function

```
let table = this.$el.querySelector('#irit_res_table');
table.table2excel({
            name: "Worksheet Name",
            filename: "SomeFile",
            fileext: ".xls"
});
alert(`exported`);
```

table dom el

```
<table id="irit_res_table" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <th v-for="option in fields_choosed_for_table" :key="option">
                                    {{ option }}
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr v-for="student in students_search" :key="student.QuestionnaireNumbers">
                                <td v-for="option in fields_choosed_for_table_keys" :key="option">
                                    {{ student[option] }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Error is:

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: table.table2excel is not a function.

Comment: Are you sure your selector (table) is working properly? Did you test it?

Comment: i tested it befor and it's work.

Comment: Share your table DOM-element

Comment: if i use a vue libary name : vue-json-excel i can download the same table.